# Variable assignments in C with comma operator

Tags: c, operators, variable-assignment

I read many questions here but couldn't find my answer, considering following statements:

```
int x;
x = 1, 2, 3;
```

this gives x value of 1 however as there are other values separated by `,` why the rest is discarded? shouldn't it be 3? or is it because of precedency of `=` over `,`?

Then if I  write

```
int x = 1, 2, 3;
```

now it doesn't compile. what's the real difference between the two?

Comment: You can verify your assumption regarding operator precedence by simply putting `1,2,3` in brackets:  `(1,2,3)`

Comment: If something does not compiler you should show the exact error message.

Comment: `x=1,` is a syntactically correct expression. `2,` is another, `3;` is another... Now, does the difference begin to make sense?

Comment: This `printf("x=%d\n", x), 42;` perhaps shows why there is a difference between `x = 1, 2, 3;` and `x = (1, 2, 3);`.

Comment: First one is a sequence of three sub-expressions executed one after another with the last one being the final result of the combined expression. You might want to play around a bit: `x = 1, y = 2, z = 3` or `z = (x = 1, y = 2)` or `z = (x = 1, 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found out that `=` has higher `precedence`.
Therefore that first code is similar to

```c
(x = 1),2, 3;
```

That means you have an assignment and you have 2 values combined by comma operator.

The assignment is evaluated to `1` (besides actually assigning a value to `x`) and you get an expression like this: `1,2,3;` which is evaluated but ignored.

In your second snippet things are different.

```c
int x =1, 2, 3;
```

Again the precedence is same.

If you add brackets `int x = (1,2,3);` you will get value `3` as you expected.

Without the brackets, the compiler expects the name of the next variable that you want to define here.
`2` and `3` are no valid identifiers to define variables and therefore the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

> `x = 1, 2, 3;`

Due to precedence, this is interpreted as `(x = 1), 2, 3;`.

> `int x = 1, 2, 3;`

In an expression statement such as `x = 1, 2, 3;`, you can use any *expression*. However, in a declaration, an *initializer* can only be an *assignment-expression* (or a list of initializers inside `{` and `}`).

The way the formal C grammar is written, the top-level operator of an *expression* can be any of the C operators, but the top-level operator of an *assignment-expression* can be any of the C operators except `,`. Therefore, if a `,` is seen when parsing the top level of an initializer, it cannot be part of the initializer, so it ends the initializer. (A `,` can appears inside parentheses in an initializer.)

Here are some details about how this works. The formal grammar says:

- An *expression* is either *expression* `,` *assignment-expression* or is an *assignment-expression*.
- An *assignment-expression* is either *unary-expression* *assignment-operator* *assignment-expression* or is a *conditional-expression*.
- A *conditional-expression* is either *logical-OR-expression* `?` *expression* `:` *conditional-expression* or is a *logical-OR-expression*.
- This chain continues through all the operators in C.

So, when a C compiler is looking for an *expression*, it notionally goes through each of these choices, accepting either a comma operator or an assignment operator or a conditional operator, and so on. When it is looking for an *assignment-expression* (in a declaration), it starts with the second choice, an assignment operator, notionally skipping over the comma as a possibility.

Comment: TYSM for much broader explanation, can you please give a short example for each list items you kindly mentioned? That would be much helpful.